# problems with loop running continuously

Tags: java

my loops problems seems to be running an not stopping
am not getting the loop to stop it running cont and wont stop

```
rate=interest/100;
double monthly_rate=rate/period;
double n=period*length;
payment = (principal * Math.pow((1 + monthly_rate), n)) / n;

System.out.printf("Test acoount amount is %.2f",payment);

for(double i=payment; n<=n; n++){
    System.out.println(i+ "" +(payment-i));

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n <= n
```

will generally always be true.

You need to figure out the terminating condition of the loop, and possibly fix the `n++` as well. It's likely to be something like:

```
for (int prd = 1; prd <= n; prd++) ...
```

which will loop `n` times with `prd` holding the values `1` through `n` inclusive.

Comment: so what line should i put in there if i want it to stop at a certain amount

Comment: In his example, `n` is the amount that your loop will stop at as already stated in the answer, "which will loop `n` times with `prd` holding the values `1` through `n` inclusive."

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is right there in the for statement itself:

```
for(double i=payment; n<=n; n++){
```

in the conditional  **n<=n**

Basically your expression will never evaluate to anything other than what it's set too, because  'n will always equal n'

What you need is for your check to be a different variable or some kind of upper limit that you wish to cut things off at eg:

```
int max = 10;
for(double i=payment; n<=max; n++){
```

How you set and / or control max depends on exactly what your trying to achieve.

Comment: am trying to generate a loop based on what type of payment a person selects whether its monthly,semi-annually or annually

Comment: paxdiablos pretty much nailed it, what you need is something like: maxnumpayments = <put max num payments here>; then something along the lines of the prd example above, with your counter going until prd <= maxnumpayments.  Documentation for for loop is basically "for(initial variable; terminating condition; iteration condition)